# I try to put some informations from a XML file to a SQL database using python

Tags: python, mysql

When I try to put in a SQL database the subelement attribute and text, I get this:

> Failed inserting record into python_users table 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'a' in 'field list'".

SQL itself it's set with a table named "valoare" and 2 areas for values("moneda" & "flux")

```py
for child in root:
    for element in child:
        for subelement in element:
            a = subelement.attrib["currency"]
            b = subelement.text
            connection = mysql.connector.connect(
                host="localhost",
                user="root",
                passwd="admin",
                database="python",
            )
            sql_insert_query = """ INSERT INTO valoare
                          (moneda, flux) VALUES (a, b)"""
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            result = cursor.execute(sql_insert_query)
            connection.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual error is caused by not [using placeholders like you're supposed to](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html).

Also, you really don't want to be reconnecting to the database like that for each element.
In addition, you can only commit when everything's done:

```py
connection = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost", user="root", passwd="admin", database="python"
)
cursor = connection.cursor()

for child in root:
    for element in child:
        for subelement in element:
            a = subelement.attrib["currency"]
            b = subelement.text
            result = cursor.execute(
                "INSERT INTO valoare (moneda, flux) VALUES (%s, %s)", (a, b)
            )

connection.commit()
```

Comment: when i put your code it gives me this "cursor.commit()
AttributeError: 'CMySQLCursor' object has no attribute 'commit'"

Comment: @TudorPopescu My bad. Meant to be `connection.commit()`.