# 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'localhost:3306', system error: Connection not available

Tags: python, mysql

When I try to run my code i get this error:

```
File "script.py", line 36, in <module>
    result  = cursor.execute(sql_insert_query)
  File "/home/rexio18/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 266, in execute
    raw_as_string=self._raw_as_string)
  File "/home/rexio18/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 405, in cmd_query
    errno=2055, values=(addr, 'Connection not available.'))
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'localhost:3306', system error: Connection not available.
```

Code:

```
for child in root:
    for element in child:
        for subelement in element:
            a = subelement.attrib['currency']
            b = subelement.text
            connection = mysql.connector.connect(host ='localhost', user ='root', passwd ='admin' , database ='python')
                    cursor = connection.cursor()
            sql_insert_query = "INSERT INTO valoare(moneda, flux) VALUES (%s, %s)",(a, b)
            result  = cursor.execute(sql_insert_query)
            connection.commit()
```

Comment: Well, **is** the server up and running at the specified host and port? Did you try to connect via telnet or any SQL client?

Comment: As I mentioned in your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55904571/i-try-to-put-some-informations-from-a-xml-file-to-a-sql-database-using-python you should not create the connections within the loop. Your MySQL server probably isn't configured for that many concurrent connections.

Comment: @akx it is the same,I ve tried what you said

Comment: @mike yes,server up and running at the specified host and port & i m using mysql workbench

Comment: Your variable `sql_insert_query` is a tuple consisting of the query string and a tuple of parameters. That raises an AttributeError [in the connection](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-python/blob/master/lib/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py#L392) when attempting to encode what is expected to be a string. From the handling of that error, the [OperationalError raises](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-python/blob/master/lib/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py#L399-L405). Very misleading, I admit. `cursor.execute(*sql_insert_query)` should fix that. Note the unpack operator (`*`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode' - MySQLdb Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352283/attributeerror-tuple-object-has-no-attribute-encode-mysqldb-python)